# Using a pointer in Swift 3 to modify Data

Tags: swift, pointers

I'm trying to figure out how to use a pointer from Data in Swift 3.  I have the following simple method in OBJ-C that modifies the 4th value in a 10 value file.  How would I accomplish this in Swift 3?

```objc
- (void) modifyFourthValueInFile:(NSString*)filePath {
     //filePath is a file that contains 10 SInt16 values
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    SInt16 *ourPointer = (SInt16*)data.bytes;
    ourPointer += 3;  // get the 4th value
    *ourPointer = 1234; // modify the 4th value
    [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach:

- Read the file into a `Data` value.
- Use `withUnsafeMutableBytes()` to mutate the bytes.
- Create a `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer`, this allows to modify
  the data via subscripting instead of pointer arithmetic.
- Write the data back to the file.
- Use do/try/catch for error handling.

Example:

```
func modifyFile(filePath: String) {
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    do {
        var data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (i16ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>) in
            let i16buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: i16ptr, count: data.count/MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride)

            i16buffer[3] = 1234 // modify the 4th value
        }
        try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I found out that the entire creating a buffer step is not needed since you can subscript the UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16> directly like this:  i16ptr[3] = 1234

Comment: @kishdude: You are right, I realized that later. Possible advantages of a buffer are: 1) bounds checking 2) it is a collection, so you can iterate over its elements.